# Jquery preserve new page design when refreshing page

Tags: jquery

I have a page containing a shopping cart: When I choose the number of articles I want to command, my page load to check if the number of articles is available in stock and if it's available it updates the field number else it shows an error message.

I should change the design of the page, with jquery directly using the javascript console.
My question is how can I preserve the same new page design(including footer and header) with jquery when refreshing page to update the field Number?

I'm new in jquery and I'm reading about ajax requets, here is the code I'm trying:
$("#selectNumber").click(function(){

```
      $.ajax({
   url : 'http://localhost/commande/mon-panier#',
   type : 'GET',
   success : function(){
            showNewDom();
        },
    error : function(){
          showNewDom();

        },
});
```

});

But this still show me the old design after page loading.

Can anyone help please to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably read about ajax requests with javascript. I also believe you meant javascript console instead of java console.

Comment: Yes javascript console :)

Comment: I tried to use $("#selectNumber]").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();}) where #selectNumberis the id of my field number but this stops page refresh and errors messages are not appearing.Any one can help please?